# What are the advantages of EJB 3.x over EJB 2.1 in testing apsect

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0

I know that there are lots of advantages of EJB3.x over EJB 2.1. 
What i need is the testing aspect. 

What re the advantages of EJB3.x in testing aspect??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note OpenEJB supports testing EJB 2.x components using the EJB 3.1 Embedded EJBContainer API.

This example shows an EJB 3.0 bean that has EJB 2.x interfaces and is unit tested with JUnit and the javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer API:

- http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/component-interfaces

That basic setup still works if all EJB 2.x features are used.  The nice thing about that example, is it can show you how to maintain your EJB 2.x views while still having an EJB 3 style bean.

This can be nice as it sounds like you might be doing some migrating from EJB 2.x to 3.x and typically the hardest thing is not deleting the xml and converting to annotations, but maintain all the code that uses the EJBHome/EJBObject interfaces (or the local versions).

Answer (score 2):

e.g. EJB 3.1 specifies an embeddable EJBContainer you can use in unit tests:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/embeddable/EJBContainer.html